# Creating an Excel multi-lookup/match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Assuming a simple workbook with two worksheets. Worksheet A and B both have an ID column that I first need to match. Worksheet B has two additional columns of text. The goal of the formula would be to provide a simple Y/N value in worksheet A If 1) Sheet B has a matching ID to the row in sheet A and either of the text columns of that matched row contains some static text. The static text to search for, in this example, would be the word "blind". I have tried to use multiple iterations of VLOOKUP, MATCH & INDEX functions but have only been able to yield a successful 1-dimensional match on ID.

[SHEET A: ID column, and the desired Y/N column from the requested formula. Also, a notes column to explain why a Y/N should be evaluated based on the data in sheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJiid.png)

```
ID   |  MATCHED BY FORMULA  |  WHY
--------------------------------------------
1    |  Y                   | ID and text match
2    |  N                   | NO ID match
3    |  N                   | NO text match
4    |  N                   | NO ID match
5    |  N                   | NO text match
```

[SHEET B: Also contains the ID to match on with sheet A. It also contains two text columns either of which (or both) could contain the static text ("blind") being searched for by the formula. The text to locate must exist in the string and does not need to be an exact match of the entire string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS45p.png)

```
ID   | TEXT1      |  TEXT2
--------------------------------
1    | three      | blind, mice
3    | mice       | see
5    | how, mice  | they
7    | run        | three
9    | blind      | mice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A2=$G$2:$G$6)*(($B$10=$H$2:$I$6))),"Y","N")
```

[image]

**Edit**

To find partial matches of string you need to use `SEARCH` function:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A2=$G$2:$G$6)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$10,$H$2:$I$6))),"Y","N")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is close. One thing I did not mention in my post is that I have a need to find substrings. So, the text might be "blind" or it might be "blind, mice". Containing the word "blind" should be enough for a match. I attempted to tweak the formula to use SEARCH but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

When things like this get tricky, it is usually best practice to use helper columns **at least** when you are trying to make one long formula. It is usually best to retain them anyways for readability.

To demonstrate this, my solution creates one formula which references these helper columns and one formula which consolidates everything into one. Please see the attached screenshots:

[Sheet A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zr59.png)

[Sheet B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ4bT.png)

[Sheet A Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE3n3.png)

Also, please note that if you are working with a very large dataset, it may be best to convert the OFFSET MATCH into an INDEX MATCH for the Text Match Column, since Offset is a volatile function.